# add unique column to a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with 10 columns. I would like to add a column which will uniquely identify every row. I do have to come up with the unique value(could be as simple as a running sequence). How can I do this? I tried adding index as a column itself but for some reason I get a KeyError when I do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add a column from range of len of you index

```
  df['new'] = range(1, len(df.index)+1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I also have a followup question. when I try to create a smaller dataframe, I get a Key Error.                                               
        df['pk_col'] = range(1, len(df.index)+1)       
        df_new = df['pk_col', 'col']

Comment: you are not slicing you dataframe correctly use `df[['pk_col', 'col']]`